# Good power supply for a Asus Z8NR-D12 motherboard? (Or: I can has dual ESP12V?)

Tags: power-supply-unit, hardware

My company is building a server and we've already purchased an Asus Z8NR-D12 motherboard which we really like, but when we went to assemble our server, we found that the chassis we had bought came with a PSU that only provides one EPS12V connector while the motherboard needs two. We had some other problems with the chassis, so we're going to return it and get a new chassis and psu.

So can anyone recommend a PSU that will work well with this motherboard? I've been doing some searches, and I'm having trouble finding one that has 2 ESP12V connectors.

I guess another option would be a molex to eps12v adapter cable. But I'm not sure how well this will work when the server is under load. My understanding is that the eps12v uses 4 pairs of wire for a reason, and pulling all that current down the single pair of a molex connector could cause problems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can buy splitters that take one EPS12V and provide two connectors to the motherboard.  This isn't ideal for a number of reasons, but it may be suitable for your situation.

I don't have any specific recommendations, but the key words you need to use in searching for suitable supplies are "Dual eps12v":

http://www.google.com/search?q=dual%20eps12v

Answer (score 1):

Original answer deleted, it was incorrect.

According to the manual, you will need a single 24-pin *and all 4 +12v sockets filled in*.  Fortunately, [google is your friend yet again, and was able to locate such a supply.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FKIQTC)